# .NET Must Specify Valid Information?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

This piece of code works fine elsewhere, the only thing that's changed is its now in a loop and I'm calling variables by item. instead of model. When I pre-define `newurl` and page content contains the code works and it parses lives as "Live" which is correct so I feel its something to do with this? However I'm getting the error below:

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Must specify valid information for parsing in the string.

On this line:

```
lives = "Live";
```

I did have this after:

```
else
{
    lives = "Dead";
}
```

However, I removed it to find the error as otherwise it just parses and sets the variable as dead.

#### Enum

```
public enum Live
{
    Indexed, Live, Dead
}
```

Though it shows that its something to do with the variables? I tried setting another variable of the object to the `newurl` string to check it was correct and it is. I also tried predefining `newurl` but not page contains and it still doesn't work so its an issue with both of these?

So I know that `item.Anchor` etc are pulling in the variables correctly it just doesn't seem to translate to working?

#### Code

```
public ActionResult CheckLinks(Link model)
{
    var items = db.Links.Where(p => p.UserTable.ID == UserTableID).ToList();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        string pageContent = null;
        string visiturl = "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:" + "http://" + item.Identifier.domain + item.Obdomain;
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(visiturl);
        HttpWebResponse myres = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myres.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        string lives = "";
        if (pageContent.Contains(item.Anchor))
        {
            lives = "Indexed";
        }
        else
        {
            string newurl = "http://" + item.Identifier.domain + item.Obdomain;
            HttpWebRequest newReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newurl);
            HttpWebResponse newres = (HttpWebResponse)newReq.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newres.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            if (pageContent.Contains(item.Anchor))
            {
                lives = "Live";
            }

            var link = db.Links.SingleOrDefault(c => c.LinkID == item.LinkID);
            link.live = (Link.Live)Enum.Parse(typeof(Link.Live), lives);
            db.Entry(link).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: It's more likely the exception is being thrown on the `Enum.Parse` line. I don't know why you don't just declare `lives` as `Link.Live` instead of a string. See also [Parse string to enum type](//stackoverflow.com/q/1424971)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that's what I figured its throwing there, however when the bit I removed is there it manages to parse that just fine? Also why does it work when the url and page contains are predefined?

Comment: When you remove that line `lives` is an empty string, which is a different value, which `Enum.Parse` succeeds with. The rest of the code in your example is only obfuscating your issue - you should reduce your code to a http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Please, share the `Link.Live` enumeration.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot actually with that line in it sets the lives to dead and saves this so its parsing fine, however its failing to set lives to anything and I wondered why the url etc wont work. Quite right on the sscce will update the code and text!

Comment: @Alexander added, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `if-else` logic. It is possible for the value of `lives` to be an empty string, which won't parse correctly.

```
string lives = "";
if (pageContent.Contains(item.Anchor))
{
    lives = "Indexed";
}
else
{
    // ...
    if (pageContent.Contains(item.Anchor))
    {
        lives = "Live";
    }
    // We can have lives == "" at this point, which Enum.Parse won't process

    // ...
}
```

Best guess is that you meant to default to `Dead`, so it will parse correctly.

```
string lives = "Dead";
```

> But then, since you have [exhaustively debugged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) this before posting your question, you already know that. Right?

As was mentioned in the comments, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use a string here, anyway. This way the compiler can detect your mistake and prevent you from compiling with it.

```
Link.Live lives = Link.Live.Dead;
if (pageContent.Contains(item.Anchor))
{
    lives = Link.Live.Indexed;
}
else
{
    // ...
    if (pageContent.Contains(item.Anchor))
    {
        lives = Link.Live.Live;
    }
    // No need to parse from a string...

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks! didn't know I could do it like that, have changed it to that to clean it up! Do you know why though using the variables from item. doesn't work? and when I predefine the variables it does? Is it due to the loop? As it still sets it to dead when it should be live

Comment: Fixed it! turns out a space was getting into it somehow? just tried it off a whym and did .replace(" ","") and it worked. Thanks for your help though